# Ошибка в цикле foreach, отсутствует массив

Tags: php, html

Помогите разобраться. HTML:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="25" name="word[]">
<input type="text" maxlength="25" name="word[]">
<input type="text" maxlength="25" name="word[]">
```

Мне нужно эти поля обработать. Обработчик:

```
$word = $_POST['word'];

foreach ($word as $key=>$val) {
...
}
```

Но почему-то цикл ругается на то, что массив отсутствует: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Всем спасибо! Проблема решена.

Comment: Тут кажется проблема в name="word[]", ни разу не видел такого

Comment: а можно увидеть полностью форму и обработчик?

Comment: @Anovoselof это вам кажется!

Answer (score 2):

Можно, все должно работать. если Вы проверяете     `$_POST['word']`    после того, как отправили форму

Comment: хоть до, хоть после!

Comment: разве если пост будет пустой - ругаться не будет, ведь $word = "";

Comment: в том то и дело что молчит!

Comment: таки да... я втулил `isset($_POST['word'])` и жду ошибку :D **З.Ы.** плюсую

Comment: >Конструкция foreach предоставляет простой способ перебора массивов. Foreach работает только с массивами и объектами, и будет генерировать ошибку при попытке использования с переменными других типов или неинициализированными переменными.     

[Источник](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 1):

честно говоря не пойму... вот без проблем все, фактически отличий нет

---

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['word']))
{
    $word = $_POST['word'];

    foreach($word as $key => $value)
    {
        echo $value;
    }
}

?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" maxlength="25" value="word 1" name="word[]" />
    <input type="text" maxlength="25" value="word 2" name="word[]" />
    <input type="text" maxlength="25" value="word 3" name="word[]" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

---

Comment: поэтому я и попросил чтобы rimlin показал полностью форму и обработчик.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action ="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST">
<input type="text" maxlength="25" name="word[]">
<input type="text" maxlength="25" name="word[]">
<input type="text" maxlength="25" name="word[]">
<input type="submit">
</form>
<?
$word = $_POST['word'];

foreach ($word as $key=>$val) {
echo "$key $val";
}
?>
```